# gawd awfull rails 3.0.0 bundler cannot load such file rubygems install insanity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an (expletive) old rails app (version 3.0.0) I'm trying to load up.
I have rbenv installed.

I'm at my wits f-ing end

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundler --version
Bundler version 2.2.7
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actioncable (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2)
actionmailbox (6.1.3.1)
actionmailer (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2, 3.0.0)
actionpack (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2, 3.0.0)
actiontext (6.1.3.1)
actionview (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2)
activejob (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2)
activemodel (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2, 3.0.0)
activerecord (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2, 3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activestorage (6.1.3.1)
activesupport (6.1.3.1, 5.0.7.2, 3.0.0)
arel (7.1.4, 1.0.1)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
bindex (0.8.1)
builder (3.2.4, 2.1.2)
bundler (2.2.7, 1.0.22)     <----- Note: the two versions
byebug (11.1.1)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.8, 1.1.6)
crass (1.0.6)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
date (default: 1.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
erubi (1.10.0)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.12.2)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
globalid (0.4.2)
i18n (1.8.7, 1.8.2, 0.4.2)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
jbuilder (2.10.0)
jquery-rails (4.3.5)
json (default: 2.1.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.19 x86_64-linux)
listen (3.0.8)
loofah (2.9.0, 2.4.0)
mail (2.7.1, 2.2.20)
marcel (1.0.1)
method_source (1.0.0, 0.9.2)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_mime (1.0.2)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.14.0, 5.10.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.5.4, 2.5.2)
nokogiri (1.11.1 x86_64-linux, 1.10.9)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
pg (0.21.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
power_assert (1.1.1)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
puma (3.12.4)
racc (1.5.2)
rack (2.2.3, 2.2.2, 1.2.8)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.5.7)
rails (3.0.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (13.0.1, 12.3.3)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
rb-inotify (0.10.1)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1.1)
ref (2.0.0)
sass (3.7.4)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sass-rails (5.0.7)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
spring (2.1.0)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
sprockets (4.0.2, 3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
test-unit (3.2.7)
therubyracer (0.12.3)
thor (1.1.0, 1.0.1, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.10)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (5.2.1)
turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
tzinfo (2.0.4, 1.2.9, 1.2.6, 0.3.60)
uglifier (4.2.0)
web-console (3.7.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zeitwerk (2.4.2)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle _1.0.22_ install
```

When I bundle...and I have to use bundle 1 or it screams at me...when I bundle I get this error

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle _1.0.22_ install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    17: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    16: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    15: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    13: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    12: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    11: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    10: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
     9: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
     8: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
     7: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `evaluate'
     6: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `new'
     5: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:14:in `initialize'
     4: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     3: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     2: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError)
```

And my Gemfile..

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'


gem 'will_paginate', '~> 2.3.17'
gem 'soap4r-middleware', '~> 0.8.6'
gem 'soap4r',  '~> 1.5.6'
gem 'prawn-labels', '~> 0.11.3.0'
gem 'nokogiri-plist', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'rails_sql_views', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
```

So I need Rails 3.0 and bundle 1.0.22 cause when I just use bundle install I get this mess...

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.2.7)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:1.0.22` and rerun bundler using `bundle _1.0.22_`
```

How can I resolve this. I'm going nuts and loosing sleep so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I tried this with the 1.9.3-p484 ruby and got this error...

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle install Fetching source index for
 rubygems.org Installing rake (13.0.3) Gem::InstallError: rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2. An error occured while installing rake (13.0.3), 
and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install rake -v '13.0.3' 
succeeds before bundling.
```

this makes no sense... bundler 1.0.22 and rake 0.9.2.2 are installed

```
fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.22)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.4.2)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
mail (2.2.20)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.2.8)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the recommended ruby version for that version of rails. Ruby 2.5.8 is far past what was used in rails 3.0.

Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0 is your best bet for rails 3.

[compatiblity-table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html)

One of these

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p484
rbenv install 2.0.0-p648
```

There are a lot of 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 versions in rbenv I suggested the ones listed [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/)

Comment: @nita I tried this with the 1.9.3-p484 ruby and got this error 

fonso@mybox:~/my-dev$ bundle install Fetching source index for rubygems.org Installing rake (13.0.3) Gem::InstallError: rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2. An error occured while installing rake (13.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install rake -v '13.0.3' succeeds before bundling.

Comment: You could try `rbenv install 2.2.10` given that message